# How do I create a synonym for a type class name?

Tags: isabelle

I want to <strike>abbreviate</strike> create a synonym for a type class name. Here's how I'm doing it now:

```
class fooC = linordered_idom
instance int :: fooC 
  proof qed

definition foof :: "'a::fooC ⇒ 'a" where
  "foof x = x"
  
term "foof (x::int)"
value "foof (x::int)"
```

This works fine if there's not a better way to do it. The disadvantage is that I have to instantiate `int`, and the `class` command takes time to implement itself.

### Update 140314

This update is to clarify for Makarius what it is I want, to explain my purpose in wanting it, and give a list of commands that I'm familiar with for creating notation, abbreviations, and synonyms, but commands which I couldn't get to work for what I want.

### My initial choice of "abbreviation" rather than "synonym"

I guess "synonym" would have been a better word, but I chose "abbreviation" because it describes what I want, which is to be able to create a shorter name for for a type class, like renaming `linordered_semidom` to `losdC`. Though Isar `abbreviation` has some of the attributes of `definition`, it also just defines syntax. So, because "abbreviate" describes what I want, and `abbreviation` just defines syntax, I chose "abbreviation" instead of "synonym" or "alias".

### Synonym/alias, Isar commands I couldn't get to work for that

"Alias" would describe what I want. As to the sentence "If you just want to save typing in the editor, you could use some abbreviations there," here are the commands I've experimented with to try and rename `linordered_idom`, but I couldn't get them to work for me:

- `type_notation`
- `type_synonym`
- `notation`
- `abbreviation`
- `syntax`

Rather than explain what I've tried, and try to remember what I tried, I just list them. I did searches on "class" and only found the Isar commands `class` and `classes`. I thought maybe locale commands might be applicable, but I didn't find anything.

What I want is simple, like how `type_synonym` is used to define synonyms for types.

### The purpose

There is my general desire to shorten type class names such as `linordered_idom`, because eventually, I plan on using the algebra type classes extensively.

However, there is a second reason, and that is to rename something like `linordered_semidom` to be part of a naming scheme of three types.

For any algebraic type class, such as `linordered_semidom`, I can use that type class, along with `quotient_type`, to create what I'll call a number system, such as how `nat` is used to define `int`.

Using `Int.thy` as a template, I did that with `linordered_semidom`, and then instantiated it as `comm_ring_1`, which is as far as I have time to go these days.

Additionally, with `typedef`, for any algebraic type class which has the dependencies of `zero` and `one` (and others such as `ord`), I can define a type of all elements greater than or equal to zero, and another one for all elements greater than zero. I did that for `linordered_idom`, but then I figured out that I actually needed to go the `quotient_type` route, to get things that model `rat`.

That's the long explanation. Eventually, I'll start working with numerous algebraic type classes, and from one type class, I'll get two more. If I do that for 20 type classes, and also use them, then long, descriptive names don't work, and renaming type classes will help me in knowing what type classes go together.

Here would be the scheme for `linordered_semidom`, where I don't know how this will actually work out, until I'm able to try it all:

1. `linordered_semidom` is the base class. I rename it to `losdC`. It's the numbers greater than or equal to zero for these three types.
2. `losdQ` is defined from `losdC` using `quotient_type`. It gives me the negative numbers, and the ability to coerce `losdC` to `losdQ`.
3. `losd1` is defined using `typedef`, and is the numbers greater than zero.

I need a consistent naming scheme, to keep it all straight: `losdC`, `losdQ`, and `losd1`.

### Finally, eventually even 4 types instead of 3 types

I haven't completely worked and thought things out (I'm not even close), but analogously, it's all related to implementing, for algebra type classes, the basic relationship between `nat`, `int`, and `rat`, where `real` might eventually come into play. Additionally, it's about getting a type, from these types, of the non-negative or positive members, if those don't come by default.

There is `nat` used for `int`, and `int` used for `rat`.

With `nat` used for `int`, we get the non-negative integers by default, which is `nat`.

With `int` used for `rat`, we don't get the non-negative members of `rat`, we get fractions. (Again, I'm talking about a type of non-negatives and positives, not a set of non-negatives and positives.)

So, if I use `linordered_idom` and `quotient_type` to define fractions, then I have to use `typedef` twice to get the non-negative and positive members of those fractions, which means I would have 4 types to keep track of, `liodC`, `liodQ`, `liod0`, and `liod1`.

If there's a simple solution to renaming type classes, then I've unnecessarily said about 600 words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A definition is not an abbreviation, it introduces a separate term that is logical equal.  That works for term constants.

A type class is semantically a predicate over types, and thus connected to some predicate (term constant), but in practice you rarely access that.
So what exactly means to "abbreviate a type class"?

For example, you might want to manipulate the class name space to get an alias for it, which is in principle possible.  But what is the purpose?

If you just want to save typing in the editor, you could use some abbreviations there.

Another possibility, within the formal system, is to introduce genuine aliases in the name space.  Isabelle provides some facilities for that, which are not very much advertized, because there is a real danger of obscuring libraries and preventing anyone else from understanding them, if names are changed too much.

This is how it works, using some friendly Isabelle/ML within the theory source:

```
class foobar = ord + fixes foobar :: 'a

setup {* Sign.class_alias @{binding f} @{class foobar} *}

typ "'a::f"

instantiation nat :: f
begin
definition foobar_nat :: nat where "foobar_nat = 0"
instance ..
end
```

Note that `Sign.class_alias` only refers to the type class name space in the narrow sense. A `class` is many things at the same time: locale, const (the prodicate), type class.  You can see this in the following examples where the class is used as "target" for local definitions and theorems:

```
definition (in foobar) "fuzz = foobar"
theorem (in foobar) "fuzz = foobar" by (simp add: fuzz_def)
```

Technically, the locale name space used above could support aliases as well, but this is not done.  Only basic `Sign.class_alias`, `Sign.type_alias`, `Sign.const_alias` are exposed for unusual situations, to address problems with legacy libraries.

Comment: Makarius, thanks for the answer. I changed my question to give you the long form of my question, and I clarified that "alias" or "synonym" is what I meant by "abbreviation". I was looking for a command like `type_synonym` to use to rename `linordered_semidom`, but I couldn't get any of the Isar commands I know about to work for me. If there's a simple solution, that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Makarius, thanks again. Works perfect. After knowing that a const/predicate is involved, I looked a little at `thm "class.linordered_semidom_def"` and `term "class.linordered_semidom"`. That info may come in useful some day.